# HTTP Status 404 - /com.demo/rest/hello - with Rest project

Tags: java, rest, maven, intellij-idea

I have to write REST projcet. But I got next message:

[image]

I folowed this tutorial [REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html).

I'm using Intellij and JDK 7.

Here is snippet from `pom` file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--JERSEY-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

from `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>com.demo</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.demo.Hello</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/res
```

t/*

content of `Hello` class:

```
package com.demo;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }
}
```

I deployed project to `Tomcat 7`:

[image]

Here is ***more info*** [Tomcat log](http://pastebin.com/dZvQx1qY)

And add all necessary jars:

[image]

It should work. Why did this happen?

***EDIT***

project struckture:

[image]

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably missed out on specifying path related to the class Hello.

Specify it as

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    @GET @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I add this of course. I missed copy here. I added link to tomcat log file.

Comment: Can you please paste the full class code starting from definition of the package it resides in?

Answer (score 0):

Your package name is just `com.demo` so 
change

```
<param-value>com.demo.Hello</param-value>
```

to

```
<param-value>com.demo</param-value>
```

Your context root is RestDemo so the url to access must be

```
localhost:8080/RestDemo/rest/hello
```

Comment: can you post the project structure or simply press ctrl+click on the com.demo and see whether it takes you to that package or not

Comment: Kepp throwing the same HTTP status.

Comment: did u change after launch url?

Comment: Yes I did it. I found strange line from console - `INFO: validateJarFile(D:\HOME\IdeaProjects\RestDemo\out\artifacts\RestDemo_war_exploded\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class`. Actually this jar is added to lib????

Comment: that means you are adding servlet-api.jar manually right but tomcat usually provides us one

Comment: good shot. Can you recommend some good tutorials about REST or SOAP with Java?